# In gigya wordpress plugin how i can use facebook like button

Tags: wordpress, facebook, gigya

I am using wordpress 3.0 and gigya plugin for connecting facebook.I want to add like button in my wordpress pages. So how i can add fb like button?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use any WP plugin for adding a facebook like button - you can generate the button code on the Facebook site and then insert it into your template.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like

From looking around it seems that Gigya were going to implement a widget back in May that did this from within their plugin, but it seems that they've forgotten all about the idea now.